# Perl Inline C: Passing Arrayref to C Function

Tags: perl, arrayref, inline-c

I can't get arrayrefs passed into a C function using Inline C.  I would like some help, please.

First, just to prove I can get Inline C to work, I'll pass a scalar value to a C function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I. 
#
# try1.pl
#
use Inline C;

my $c = 3.8;
foo( $c );

__END__
__C__
void foo( double c )
{
   printf( "C = %f\n", c );
}
```

And run it:

```
% ./try1.pl
C = 3.800000
```

Now do the same thing, but with an arrayref:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I. 
# 
# try2.pl
#
use Inline C;

my @abc = (1.9, 2.3, 3.8);
foo( \@abc );

__END__
__C__
void foo( double *abc )
{
    printf( "C = %f\n", abc[2] );
}
```

Run it:

```
% ./try2.pl
Undefined subroutine &main::foo called at ./try1.pl line 7.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?   Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am new to Perl but line 7 is the line you define the array on, are you defining the array correctly. Are you passing in correctly (with the /?) Does it need to be converted to a C array via something in the A.P.I (Not how this is working XD)?

Answer (score 15):

Inline::C is smart enough to extract values from `SV`'s based on your C function's type signature. But if you want to pass complex Perl structures to C functions you'll need to use the [Perl API](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html) to extract the values. So, here's what you need to know for this problem:

An array is an instance of a C `struct` called `AV`. A reference is implemented by a `struct` called an `RV`. All of these are "subtypes" (kinda) of a base `struct` called `SV`.

So to make this function work we need to do a few things.

1. Change the parameter type to `SV *` (pointer to an `SV`).
2. Use the API to check if this particular `SV` is a reference as opposed to some other kind of scalar
3. Check the RV to make sure it's pointing at an array and not something else.
4. Dereference the `RV` to get the `SV` that it points to.
5. Since we know that `SV` is an array, cast it to `AV` and start working with it.
6. Lookup the third element of that array, which is another `SV`.
7. Check that the `SV` we got from the array is a numerical value suitable for C `printf`
8. Extract the actual numerical out of the `SV`.
9. Print the message

So putting that all together, we get something like this:

```
use Inline C;

my @abc = (1.9, 2.3, 3.8);
foo( \@abc );

__END__
__C__
void foo( SV *abc )
{
    AV *array;     /* this will hold our actual array */
    SV **value;    /* this will hold the value we extract, note that it is a double pointer */
    double num;    /* the actual underlying number in the SV */

    if ( !SvROK( abc ) ) croak( "param is not a reference" );
    if ( SvTYPE( SvRV( abc ) ) != SVt_PVAV ) croak( "param is not an array reference" );

    /* if we got this far, then we have an array ref */
    /* now dereference it to get the AV */
    array = (AV *)SvRV( abc );

    /* look up the 3rd element, which is yet another SV */
    value = av_fetch( array, 2, 0 );

    if ( value == NULL ) croak( "Failed array lookup" );
    if ( !SvNOK( *value ) ) croak( "Array element is not a number" );

    /* extract the actual number from the SV */
    num = SvNV( *value );

    printf( "C = %f\n", num );
}
```

Kinda makes you appreciate how much work Perl does under-the-hood. :)

Now, you don't have to be as super-explicit as that example. You could get rid of some of the temp variables by doing things inline, e.g.

```
printf( "C = %f\n", SvNV( *value ) );
```

would eliminate the need to declare `num`. But I wanted to make it clear how much dereferencing and type-checking is needed to traverse a Perl structure in C.

And as @mob points out below, you don't actually have to do *all* that work (though it's a good idea to be familiar with how it works.)

Inline::C is smart enough that if you declare your function as

```
void foo( AV *abc ) { 
   ...
}
```

It will automatically unwrap the `AV` for you and you can go straight to the `av_fetch` step.

If all of that seems baffling to you, I highly recommend taking a look at:

1. The [Perlguts Illustrated](http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/GAAS/illguts-0.09.pdf) PDF, then
2. The [`perlguts`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) manpage, and then
3. The [Inline::C Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/Inline::C-Cookbook), while consulting
4. The [`perlapi`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html) manpage.

Comment: OK to declare the function `void foo(AV* array) { ...` and let Perl/Inline::C handle the first three steps.

Comment: What a complete answer @friedo.  Thank you, too, mob !

Answer (score 4):

In your [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/~sisyphus/Inline/C/C.pod) code:

```
void foo( SV *reference ) {
  AV *array;

  array = (AV *)SvRV( reference );

  ...
}
```

Then deal with the array value as the `AV` type. See the [Perl Inline::C Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/~sisyphus/Inline-0.53/C/C-Cookbook.pod).

Comment: Why not just `void foo( AV* array ) { ...` ?

Answer (score 3):

Wrong data type.

```
use Inline 'C';

my @abc = (1.9, 2.3, 3.8);
foo( \@abc );

__END__
__C__
void foo(SV* abc) {
    sv_dump(abc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   

And how would I access the 3rd element of SV *abc?